# Does a peaceful workplace trump everything else? Is a stressful environment worth it?

Tags: work-environment, career-development, colleagues, job-change

I've been working at a great job for six months, where I feel genuinely appreciated and valued. On the other hand, I'm slightly bored. But I do get to do things at my own pace and this has allowed me to learn and to get personal satisfaction from my work. The people I work with, especially my manager, are great. Things are fit around me to a degree, for example I can come to work at a time that suits me (usually quite late).

I have an offer for a workplace that does client work, it would probably be more stressful, but I would have the chance to work of technically more challenging things. I would have the chance to work on computer games which is my boyhood dream. The people I'd be working with would probably be fine, it would be a larger group and more people to learn from, but I get the sense they would be generally more pressured. The demographics would be skewed younger, so perhaps there would be more immaturity.

I was wondering if someone further along in their career than me could share something of their experience in terms of moving from a higher stress environment for the sake of technical experience was worth it.

Comment: This is absolutely impossible to answer for you.  Some people prefer a busy workplace, others prefer a quiet, peaceful one.  Only you can say which is best for you.

Comment: Working on computer games, you can expect the worst working conditions. This can turn from boyhood dream to nightmare.

Comment: As others have said, this is a question only you can answer, but I'd give this bit of advice: trust your instincts, and don't worry that it is the 'wrong' choice, the one that someone with 'more experience' would never choose. Both choices are regularly made by people with more experience. Trust what your gut tells you that you do want, don't try to second-guess it with what you think that you should want.

Answer (score 1):

There are different kinds of stress. Sometimes a little stress can keep the day exciting and the knowledge that a deadline is fast approaching can be the extra push it takes to move something from the idea stage to the complete stage. Also, really important jobs are by nature very, very stressful - I can't imagine a firefighter, for example, ever describing his job as low stress. I'd even go so far as to say that to a certain point, low to no stress on a job means you're not being pushed (or pushing yourself) and you risk becoming complacent.

On the other hand, unnecessary distress can shorten your life and make a job unbearable. I think different people have different thresholds of what they can handle from micromanaging bosses, constantly changing requirements and deadlines and so on, so I have to say in specific that you need to find your own level, but generally speaking, there is nothing inherently wrong with the concept of a stressful job.

Comment: To use the jargon terms:  there's stress, and there's distress.  The former can be enjoyable challenge. The latter...

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the person and situation.  I know of plenty of people including myself who've left jobs partly out of lack of challenge and boredom.  Working on a product that excites you can also bring a lot of job satisfaction.

But on the flip side, having a job with co workers you like I think plays a huge part, if not the biggest part, in job satisfaction.  The video games industry is often (but not always) not only stressful, but quite unstable as well.  Layoffs are pretty frequent, projects get cancelled, and oftentimes you'll end up working contract, and constantly job searching.

In other words, there's good and bad to both routes.